# sent laravel ( app()->getLocale() ) with url from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel, url, amcharts

I've added other languages ​​to the site I'm working on .

I make the the medalware :

```
    class SetLocale {
         public function handle($request, Closure $next)
                {
                   App()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
                   return $next($request);
                }
              }
```

the route :

```
  Route::group(
  ['prefix' => '{locale}', 
  'where' => ['locale' => 'en|fr|ar'],
  'middleware' => 'setlocale'],function ()
        {
           Route::get('mapData','HomPageController@mapData')->name('mapData');
        });
```

and everything works perfectly , but : I have a map from https://www.amcharts.com/ that stop working because I didn't figure out how to pass the

```
    app()->getLocale()
```

in side the cod of map that is in JavaScript language

```
      polygonSeries.dataSource.url = "mapData";
```

So how can I pass the    **$langLocale** in dataSource.url to be like this

```
polygonSeries.dataSource.url = "mapData",  app()->getLocale();
```

I made a way to make it work but this way it's static not dynamic this is what I did :

```
       polygonSeries.dataSource.url = "/en/mapData";
```

so is there any way to figure out what is the the language that comes from this code **app()->getLocale();** and send it as parameter form JavaScript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the answer : put the cod of JavaScript in function and just send it the value from php file

```
  <script>
mapJs("  {{route('mapData',app()->getLocale())}}");
</script>
```

in the javascript file start the the code like this :

```
function mapJs(value) {
  polygonSeries.dataSource.url = value;
 }
```